# Is there a way to use RTK query hooks like loading , success , error multiple times in a same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

Edit Profile Feature: I Have a Component Where i get profile data from server and i display it in input fields then edit data send new data to server.

```
const {data,isLoading,isFetching,error,isError,isSuccess}=useGetProfileQuery('profile');
```

with this query i am using isLoading to show activity indicator and error message ,and also data from response.

then use below mutation to send back data to server within this same component.i want to show activity indicator and success , error mutations for below req too.

```
  const[updateUser]=useUpdateProfileMutation();
```

Comment: you can access isLoading like : ```const[updateUser, {isLoading , ...}]=useUpdateProfileMutation();```

Comment: if i do this i am getting variables already declared

Comment: then rename them like: ```const [uploadUser, { isLoading: updateLoading, ...}] = useUpdateProfileMutaion()```